# MYSQL error, I can't seem to figure it out

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE words (
word_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT,
lang_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
intro TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
home VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
forum_home VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
'language' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
register VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
login VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
logout VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
new_thread VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
subject VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
body VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
submit VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
posted_on VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
posted_by VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
replies VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
latest_reply VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
post_a_reply VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (word_id),
UNIQUE (lang_id)
);
```

Upon running I get the error

> (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''language' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
>   register VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>   login VARCHAR(' at line 9 )

I am a beginner at MySql Thank you in advance!

Comment: `'language'` can't be in single quotes. Put it in ticks instead.

Comment: @user3394016, first of all you should must see your Query. And then you sure can't clear this error then after you should post question, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`'`**](http://newwaysministryblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/computer_key_quotation_marks.png) should be `` ` `` a [backtick](http://blog.readability.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/backtick.png)

```
   'language' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL 
-- ^        ^  or just language
```

side note it is a general good practice to always use backticks (`) to enclose column/table names.

Comment: @Grijesh, +1 for Easily(Quickly) understanding for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the '' or use `` instead, and this will fix it !!

```
CREATE TABLE words (
word_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT,
lang_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
intro TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
home VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
forum_home VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
language VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
register VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
login VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
logout VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
new_thread VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
subject VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
body VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
submit VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
posted_on VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
posted_by VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
replies VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
latest_reply VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
post_a_reply VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (word_id),
UNIQUE (lang_id)
);
```